# CakePHP3 plugin test Class 'Cake\TestSuite\IntegrationTestCase' not found

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

I'm new using this framework and I've found a problem at the moment of testing a plugin.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Cake\TestSuite\IntegrationTestCase' not found in /var/www/MyApp/plugins/MyPlugin/tests/TestCase/Controller/UsersControllerTest.php on line 11
```

Running the main application works well, but I have the same problem with all the test's classes of the plugin.

The head of the test's classes is similar to:

```
<?php
namespace MyPlugin\Test\TestCase\Controller;

use Cake\TestSuite\IntegrationTestCase;
use MyPlugin\Controller\UsersController;

class UsersControllerTest extends IntegrationTestCase
{
```

The phpunit.xml.dist of the plugin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><phpunit
colors="true"
processIsolation="false"
stopOnFailure="false"
syntaxCheck="false"
bootstrap="./tests/bootstrap.php"
>
<php>
    <ini name="memory_limit" value="-1"/>
    <ini name="apc.enable_cli" value="1"/>
</php>

<!-- Add any additional test suites you want to run here -->
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="MyPlugin Test Suite">
        <directory>./tests/TestCase</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>

<!-- Setup a listener for fixtures -->
<listeners>
    <listener
    class="\Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\FixtureInjector"
    file="../../vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/Fixture/FixtureInjector.php">
        <arguments>
            <object class="\Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\FixtureManager" />
        </arguments>
    </listener>
</listeners>

<!-- Prevent coverage reports from looking in tests and vendors -->
<filter>
    <blacklist>
        <directory suffix=".php">./vendor/</directory>
        <directory suffix=".ctp">./vendor/</directory>

        <directory suffix=".php">./tests/</directory>
        <directory suffix=".ctp">./tests/</directory>
    </blacklist>
</filter></phpunit>
```

And the composer.json:

```
{
"name": "your-name-here/MyPlugin",
"description": "MyPlugin plugin for CakePHP",
"type": "cakephp-plugin",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.16",
    "cakephp/cakephp": "~3.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "*"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "MyPlugin\\": "src"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "MyPlugin\\Test\\": "tests",
        "Cake\\Test\\": "/var/www/MyApp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/tests",
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got it fixed. In the phpunit.xml.dist file of the plugin, I made the bootstrap point to the one of the main application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><phpunit
colors="true"
processIsolation="false"
stopOnFailure="false"
syntaxCheck="false"
bootstrap="../../config/bootstrap.php"
>
```

Also, in the same file, do not forget to make the listener in the same file point to the vendor of the main application, so that you don't have to re-install the entire CakePHP suite in your plugin:

```
<!-- Setup a listener for fixtures -->
<listeners>
    <listener
    class="\Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\FixtureInjector"
    file="../../vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/Fixture/FixtureInjector.php">
        <arguments>
            <object class="\Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\FixtureManager" />
        </arguments>
    </listener>
</listeners>
```

It appears that by default, when baking a plugin, these two elements are not set the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `composer install` in your plugin folder so that the CakePHP lib in installed under `<your-plugin>/vendor/cakephp/cakephp`

Comment: Thanks, but I tried it and it doesn't seem to work. Also, I guess it would be quite redundant to get all the cakephp core library in each plugin you want to test, I cannot figure out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since CakePHP 3.7 you should use

```
Application::addPlugin()
```

So in setUp() method it would be something like:

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    (new \App\Application(APP . 'config' . DS))->addPlugin('YourPlugin');
    //other options
}
```